# Example code for jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, image, modal-dialog

I need to create a jquery modal dialog with an image inside the modal box.
The dialog box should be closed only when user click on the image.

I never use jquery;Can someone provide me an example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout code examples @ http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Answer (score 1):

take a look at Jquery UI its the most common dialog box in the jquery world ;)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Try this:

html:

```
  <a href="#" id="target">derp</a>
    <div id="dialog"><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3"/></div>
```

jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#target').click(function() {

                 $('#dialog').dialog('open');

    return false;
    });

    $('img').click(function() {

         $('#dialog').dialog('close');

    });
    });
```

Comment: thanks kim,but in dialog modal demo there isn't an example about add image in dialog box and how close it after a click on image.

Can someone provide me an example code?

Comment: It doesn't work,alternatively how can I add a link in a button?